# ocmock's invokeBlockWithArgs using a nil argument

Tags: ocmock

is there any way to invoke a block with `nil` as a given argument, given that the `invokeBlockWithArgs:` requires the args to be nil-terminated?

example method definition in a mocked object:

```
- (void)methodWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSString*, NSError* )) completionBlock;
```

The given mockObject should call:

```
completionBlock(@"foo", nil);
```

however, with `invokeBlockWithArgs`:

```
OCMStub([mockObj methodWithCompletion:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:@"foo", nil, nil])]);
```

Method fails, with too few arguments; obviously with nil being the termination, it doesn't recognize the second parameter to the block should be `nil`.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested it but theoretically passing `[NSNull null]` should work.

Comment: I believe I tested that, and does not work.. Moreso, the code checks "if (error)", which if set to [NSNull null] will always fire; which is not the path to be tested..

Comment: The code in OCMock will not pass on the `NSNull` instance. It will replace it with `nil` (see: https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/60c7b46bb571be15e511ab08dfa4f72c7fe92d6d/Source/OCMock/NSInvocation%2BOCMAdditions.m#L121-L132) Can you please check whether this really doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the existing answers here, passing `[NSNull null]` does what you want in this case, which is passing `nil` as the param there.

I had a case (shown below) where my logic tested the existence of an error object OR my array was empty, and wanted my test to cover *both cases* and was afraid I'd only be able to test one case

`if (error || array.count == 0) {
   // fail here
}`

Here is my test OCMock code:

`NSArray *emptyArray = @[];
OCMStub([requestMock loadListWithCompletion:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:emptyArray, [NSNull null], nil])]);`

...and in the actual invocation of that method, the error param (that I passed `[NSNull null]` into) was indeed `nil`, so the logic fell through to the empty array and the error case was still handled.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [NSNull null]. I just tested, it works.